# How do I find out how to put together a WFS GetFeature query?

Tags: geoserver, wfs, getfeature

I am new with WFS and GeoServer.

My goal is to search objects on a GeoServer via WFS.

To get started, I use the [documentation](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html). I already have problems at the beginning.

---

The request

```
http://localhost/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&
  version=1.1.0&
  request=GetCapabilities
```

shows me the following in the browser Firefox:

```
GeoServer Web Feature ServiceThis is the reference implementation of WFS 1.0.0 and WFS 1.1.0, supports all WFS operations including Transaction.WFSWMSGEOSERVERWFS1.1.0NONENONEThe Ancient GeographersClaudius PtolomaeusChief GeographerAlexandriaEgyptclaudius.ptolomaeus@gmail.com1.0.01.1.0text/xmlServiceIdentificationServiceProviderOperationsMetadataFeatureTypeListFilter_Capabilitiestext/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1resultshitstext/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1GML2KMLSHAPE-ZIPapplication/gml+xml; version=3.2application/jsonapplication/vnd.google-earth.kml xmlapplication/vnd.google-earth.kml+xmlcsvgml3gml32jsontext/xml; subtype=gml/2.1.2text/xml; subtype=gml/3.22ALLSOMEresultshitstext/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1GML2KMLSHAPE-ZIPapplication/gml+xml; version=3.2application/jsonapplication/vnd.google-earth.kml xmlapplication/vnd.google-earth.kml+xmlcsvgml3gml32jsontext/xml; subtype=gml/2.1.2text/xml; subtype=gml/3.2text/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1GenerateNewUseExistingReplaceDuplicateALLSOMEQueryInsertUpdateDeleteLockgml:Envelopegml:Pointgml:LineStringgml:PolygonLessThanGreaterThanLessThanEqualToGreaterThanEqualToEqualToNotEqualToLikeBetweenNullCheckabsabs_2abs_3abs_4acosAddCoveragesAffineAggregateAreaarea2AreaGridasinatanatan2attributeCountBandMergeBandSelectBarnesSurfacebetweenboundaryboundaryDimensionboundedByBoundsbufferBufferFeatureCollectionbufferWithSegmentsCategorizeceilcentroidclassifyClassifyByRangeClipCollectGeometriesCollection_AverageCollection_BoundsCollection_CountCollection_MaxCollection_MedianCollection_MinCollection_NearestCollection_SumCollection_UniqueConcatenatecontainsContourcontrastconvertconvexHullConvolveCoveragecosCountCoverageClassStatsCropCoveragecrossesdarkendateDifferencedateFormatdateParsedesaturatedifferencedimensiondisjointdisjoint3Ddistancedistance3Ddouble2boolendAngleendPointenvenvelopeEqualAreaEqualIntervalequalsExactequalsExactToleranceequalToexpexteriorRingFeatureFeatureClassStatsfloorgeometrygeometryTypegeomFromWKTgeomLengthgetGeometryNgetXgetYgetzgrayscalegreaterEqualThangreaterThanGridHeatmaphslidIEEEremainderif_then_elseinin10in2in3in4in5in6in7in8in9InclusionFeatureCollectionint2bboolint2ddoubleinteriorPointinteriorRingNInterpolateintersectionIntersectionFeatureCollectionintersectsintersects3DisClosedisCoverageisEmptyisInstanceOfisLikeisNullisometricisRingisSimpleisValidisWithinDistanceisWithinDistance3DJenksJifflejsonPointerlengthlessEqualThanlessThanlightenlistlistMultiplylogLRSGeocodeLRSMeasureLRSSegmentmaxmax_2max_3max_4minmin_2min_3min_4mincircleminimumdiameterminrectanglemixmoduloMultiplyCoveragesNearestNormalizeCoveragenotnotEqualTonumberFormatnumberFormat2numGeometriesnumInteriorRingnumPointsoctagonalenvelopeoffsetoverlapsparameterparseBooleanparseDoubleparseIntparseLongpgNearestpiPointBufferspointNPointStackerPolygonExtractionpowpropertyPropertyExistsQuantileQueryrandomRangeLookupRasterAsPointCollectionRasterZonalStatisticsRasterZonalStatistics2RecodeRectangularCliprelaterelatePatternReprojectrescaleToPixelsrintroundround_2roundDoublesaturateScaleCoveragesetCRSshadeSimplifysinSnapspinsqrtStandardDeviationstartAnglestartPointstrAbbreviatestrCapitalizestrConcatstrDefaultIfBlankstrEndsWithstrEqualsIgnoreCasestrIndexOfstringTemplatestrLastIndexOfstrLengthstrMatchesstrPositionstrReplacestrStartsWithstrStripAccentsstrSubstringstrSubstringStartstrToLowerCasestrToUpperCasestrTrimstrTrim2strURLEncodeStyleCoveragesymDifferencetantinttoDegreestoRadianstouchestoWKTTransformTransparencyFillunionUnionFeatureCollectionUniqueUniqueIntervalVectorToRasterVectorZonalStatisticsverticeswithin
```

I was expecting to see what features I could use here.

---

The request

```
    http://localhost/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&
  request=DescribeFeatureType
```

shows me the following in an editor

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2">
```

I expected a list of the `feature types` available.

---

Next I tried

```
    http://localhost/geoserver/wfs?
  service=wfs&
  version=2.0.0&
  request=GetFeature&
  typeNames=namespace:featuretype
```

that returned me

```
Unknown namespace [namespace]
```

---

And last but not least I tried with names I expected as `namespace` and `featuretype`

```
   http://localhost/geoserver/wfs?
  service=wfs&
  version=2.0.0&
  request=GetFeature&
  typeNames=JAN_ALKIS:flur
```

This tells me the following in the browser

```
Feature type JAN_ALKIS:flur unknown
```

How do I find out how to put together a WFS GetFeature query?

**Edit:**

The request

```
http://localhost/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&
  version=1.1.0&
  request=GetCapabilities
```

shows me the following in the browser Chrome:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<wfs:WFS_Capabilities xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:KRE_ALKIS="KRE_ALIKS" xmlns:KRE_KANAL="KRE_KANAL" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://172.16.206.128:8080/geoserver/schemas/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd" updateSequence="654">
<ows:ServiceIdentification>
<ows:Title>GeoServer Web Feature Service</ows:Title>
<ows:Abstract>
This is the reference implementation of WFS 1.0.0 and WFS 1.1.0, supports all WFS operations including Transaction.
</ows:Abstract>
<ows:Keywords>
<ows:Keyword>WFS</ows:Keyword>
<ows:Keyword>WMS</ows:Keyword>
<ows:Keyword>GEOSERVER</ows:Keyword>
</ows:Keywords>
.....
```

[image]

Comment: looks like you need a better browser - you should be able to see the XML. Try chrome or firefox

Comment: The WFS standards would give a better overview perhaps: https://www.ogc.org/standards/wfs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a browser that is capable of displaying XML to be able to get into this - I recommend Chrome or Firefox. Clearly your `GetCapabilities` request has been striped of the tags that make it meaningful. On a local instance I get an 86kB file that starts:

```
<wfs:WFS_Capabilities xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:cite="http://www.opengeospatial.net/cite" xmlns:tiger="http://www.census.gov" xmlns:nurc="http://www.nurc.nato.int" xmlns:sde="http://geoserver.sf.net" xmlns:it.geosolutions="http://www.geo-solutions.it" xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp" xmlns:sf="http://www.openplans.org/spearfish" xmlns:zoomstack="http://ianturton.com/zoomstack" xmlns:osopen_zoomstack="http://ianturton.com/osopen_zoomstack" xmlns:rasters="http://rasters" xmlns:osm="http://ianturton.com/osm" xmlns:osdata="http://os.uk/data" xmlns:osopen="http://ianturton.com/osopen" xmlns:ian="http://ianturton.com/ian" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd" updateSequence="7100">
  <ows:ServiceIdentification>
    <ows:Title>GeoServer Web Feature Service</ows:Title>
    <ows:Abstract>This is the reference implementation of WFS 1.0.0 and WFS 1.1.0, supports all WFS operations including Transaction.</ows:Abstract>
    <ows:Keywords>
      <ows:Keyword>WFS</ows:Keyword>
      <ows:Keyword>WMS</ows:Keyword>
      <ows:Keyword>GEOSERVER</ows:Keyword>
    </ows:Keywords>
    <ows:ServiceType>WFS</ows:ServiceType>
    <ows:ServiceTypeVersion>1.1.0</ows:ServiceTypeVersion>
```

Which just tells me that this is a WFS, it's version 1.1.0 and if you are lucky tells you who owns this server (usually this is Claudius Ptolomaeus who is in charge of much of the worlds GeoSpatial infrastructure).

There are then sections that tell you (or a client program) what `requests` the service will answer, we can usually skip over these unless we want to do something odd. Basically, the only ones we ever care about are `GetCapabilities` (which we've already used), `DescribeFeatureType` and `GetFeature`.

The rest of the file is a list of available `FeatureTypes` (or layers) that we can ask questions about. For example:

```
<FeatureType xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp">
  <Name>topp:tasmania_roads</Name>
  <Title>Tasmania roads</Title>
  <Abstract>Main Tasmania roads</Abstract>
  <ows:Keywords>
    <ows:Keyword>Roads</ows:Keyword>
    <ows:Keyword>Tasmania</ows:Keyword>
  </ows:Keywords>
  <DefaultSRS>urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:4326</DefaultSRS>
  <ows:WGS84BoundingBox>
    <ows:LowerCorner>145.19754 -43.423512</ows:LowerCorner>
    <ows:UpperCorner>148.27298000000002 -40.852802</ows:UpperCorner>
  </ows:WGS84BoundingBox>
</FeatureType>
```

This gives me a **name** (`topp:tasmainia_roads`), hopefully some other human readable data like a title, abstract and keywords (don't hold your breath hoping for these though), a note of the Spatial Reference System (SRS or projection) the data is in (lat/lon degrees here) and finally, the WGS84 bounding box of the data set (again this might just be the whole world on lazy sites).

So to simply request some data I can make a request like:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&typeName=topp:tasmania_roads
```

where I specify the `service` (`WFS`), `request` type (`GetFeature`), the `version` number (`1.1.0`) and the `typeName` I'm interested in (`topp:tasmania_roads`) exactly as given in the capabilities document. This gives me a screen full of XML (GML to be specific).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>                                          
<wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" numberOfFeatures="14" timeStamp="2019-12-06T15:54:59.071Z" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd http://www.openplans.org/topp http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&amp;version=1.1.0&amp;request=DescribeFeatureType&amp;typeName=topp%3Atasmania_roads">
  <gml:featureMembers>                                                          
    <topp:tasmania_roads gml:id="tasmania_roads.1">                             
      <topp:the_geom>                                                           
        <gml:MultiLineString srsName="urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:4326" srsDimension="3">
          <gml:lineStringMember>                                                
            <gml:LineString>                                                    
              <gml:posList>-41.241 146.469 -41.241 -41.251 146.575 -41.251 -41.255 146.64 -41.255 -41.332 146.766 -41.332 -41.344 146.794 -41.344 -41.363 146.822 -41.363 -41.38 146.863 -41.38 -41.379 146.9 -41.379 -41.378 146.93 -41.378 -41.356 147.008 -41.356 -41.363 147.098 -41.363</gml:posList>
            </gml:LineString>                                                   
          </gml:lineStringMember>                                               
        </gml:MultiLineString>                                                  
      </topp:the_geom>                                                          
      <topp:TYPE>street</topp:TYPE>                                             
    </topp:tasmania_roads>                                                      
    <topp:tasmania_roads gml:id="tasmania_roads.2">
```

If however, we wanted to know what the "schema" or `FeatureType` of a layer was before we grabbed all the data then we could make a `DescribeFeatureType` request using a URL like:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&request=DescribeFeatureType&version=1.1.0&typeName=topp:tasmania_roads
```

Everything is exactly the same as the `GetFeature` request except the `request` which is changed to `DescribeFeatureType`. This returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.openplans.org/topp">
  <xsd:import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/gml/3.1.1/base/gml.xsd"/>
  <xsd:complexType name="tasmania_roadsType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="the_geom" nillable="true" type="gml:MultiLineStringPropertyType"/>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="TYPE" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:element name="tasmania_roads" substitutionGroup="gml:_Feature" type="topp:tasmania_roadsType"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

Which tells us (or our client) to expect Features with two attributes "the_geom" (a MultiLineString) and "TYPE" (a String). Both attributes are optional (minOccurs=0) and could be NULL (nillable="true").

### Note

In all the URLs the keywords (request, version, typeName) are case insensitive while the parameters are not - so reQueSt=WFS will work, typeName=TOPP:TASMANIA_Roads will not.

Comment: Thank you Ian. I use Firefox on Ubuntu and here I usually get XML files with tags. But because of your note, I have opened the file in Chrome. Here I see the tags. But also a message at the beginning: 
"This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it."
I've added this information to the top of the question with a picture. 
Is it possible that something is not configured correctly on the GeoServer?

Is my approach to figure out how to create the query the right way?

Answer (score 0):

you can reference this offical tutorial: https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).